# LINQ Query - Get the latest record by key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following query which returns me a list of guests along with a list of RSVPs. However since a user can have multiple RSVPs per event, I would only like to get the latest. RSVPs table has a submitted date column.

```
from guest in Guests
                join rsvp in RSVPs.Where(o => o.EventID == "1234")
                on guest.UserName equals rsvp.UserName into sr
                from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                     guest,
                    x
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `orderby x.DateProperty descending` ?

Answer (score 0):

Order by the date and take 1:

```
(from guest in Guests
            join rsvp in RSVPs.Where(o => o.EventID == "1234")
            on guest.UserName equals rsvp.UserName into sr
            from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            orderby x.RSVPDate desc
            select new
            {
                 guest,
                x
            })
.Take(1);
```

Comment: This only works per guest. I want to be able to do it for multiple guests

Answer (score 0):

pseudoly -

```
group x by username into g
select new {
  UserName = g.key // username
  FirstRsvp = g.OrderByDescending(item => item.RsvpDate).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

And hopefully this is LINQ to objects as this sort of thing may not be defined in a SQL provider. If it is SQL and it's not implemented, .AsEnumerable() will pull the query into memory and then it'll be L2O from there on.

Answer (score 0):

```
from guest in Guests
                join rsvp in RSVPs.Where(o => o.EventID == "1234")
                on guest.UserName equals rsvp.UserName into sr
                from x in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                     guest,
                    guest.RSVPs.Where(o => o.EventID =="1234")
                               .OrderByDesc(o=>o.SubmittedDate)
                               .FirstOrDefault()
                }
```

In fact, you might try this one as well, the idea is you load the right RSVP and load the attached guest objects, given there is a foreign key relationship.

```
context.RSVPs.Include("Guest").Where(o => o.EventID =="1234").OrderByDesc(o=>o.SubmittedDate).FirstOrDefault()
```

Else this might be an option:

```
(from rsvp in context.RSVP
where rsvp.EventId == "1234"
join guest in context.Guests on rsvp.UserName equals guest.UserName 
select new {rsvp, guest}
orderby desc rsvp.SubmittedDate).FirstOrDefault()
```